# "GenericError" when trying to transfer money to bank

Tags: php, paypal

I have used USD as a currency , also It is working good when using with Sandbox Account

[image]

I am getting Genetic error code, and Everything looks blank.

genericError?code=VU5TVVBQT1JURURfUEFZRUVfQ1VSUkVOQ1k%3D

Answer (score 1):

Generic Error **VU5TVVBQT1JURURfUEFZRUVfQ1VSUkVOQ1k** is straight forward and it is related to UNSUPPORTED_PAYEE_CURRENCY

Make sure your currencies are configured properly. Make sure you are withdrawing only INR to indian banks.

Comment: I have used USD as a currency , also It is working good when use Sandbox Account..

Comment: What currency u mentioned in your code? Make sure you mentioned everywhere USD. Make USD primary in your paypal settings.

Comment: I have used USD as a currency,  I need to check primary currency in PayPal